# What exactly is a hyperparameter?

Tags: terminology, definition, hyperparameter

Title says it all.

I have seen both "the hyperparameter of the Dirichlet distribution" and "the parameter of the Dirichlet distribution"

What are the differences?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter

Comment: See also the answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149098/what-do-we-mean-by-hyperparameters/149106#149106)

Comment: @Glen_b, it seems that we have three identical threads asking about a definiton of hyperparameter. I suggest to merge (moving the answers) all of them into http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208225. But your answer here is accepted and you will lose this green tick if this answer is moved. What do you think?

Comment: @amoeba I don't really mind about the tick. I'll have a closer look at the threads; a certain degree of caution is called for with merging.

Comment: @Glen_b: Shall I raise this as a suggestion on meta, or is it okay to leave it as a pending flag for the moderators to figure out?

Comment: @amoeba There's no harm doing both. Asking on meta is probably a good idea, especially since more people can have input (actually, there's no convenient way for even the mods to discuss a flag - we can't attach comments to a flag with our thoughts on what should be done, for example).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A hyperparameter is a parameter for the (prior) distribution of some parameter.

So for a simple example, let's say we state that the variance parameter $\tau^2$ in some problem has a uniform prior on $(0,\theta)$.

(I personally would be unlikely to do such a thing, but it happens; I might in some very particular circumstance)

Then $\tau^2$ is a parameter (in the distribution of the data) and $\theta$ is a [hyperparameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter).

If we then in turn specify a (prior) distribution for $\theta$ (e.g. that it's Gamma with mean 100 and shape parameter 2), that's a hyperprior - a prior distribution on a parameter of a prior distribution.

Comment: how is that related to the hyperparameters of ML algorithms?

Comment: never mind, I just went through the duplicate question

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149098/what-do-we-mean-by-hyperparameters/149106#149106